# What is the sequence of commit merge pull push?

Tags: git, git-branch, git-push, git-pull

I have cloned from a remote git server.

I have created a new branch (for example dev) from my local master and doing some work on the code.
I do these works to send my changes to remote repo. Are they in right sequence?

1. commit changes on dev branch
2. checkout to master branch
3. merge from dev on master
4. pull from remote repo
5. push my master to remote repo

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track indeed.

This is the wayo to work.
You make changes, commit and the push them.

```bash
# Checkout the branch you wish to start from
git checkout base_branch    

# Checkout your new branch
git checkout -b new_branch

# Change your code and add it to the staging area
git add -A . 

# Commit the code to the new branch
git commit -m "Message"

# Update the local repo with the latest code    
git fetch --all --prune

# Checkout the base branch
git checkout base_branch

# Update the local branch
git pull origin base_branch

# Merge the changes to your base branch
git merge new_branch

# Push the changes to the server
git push origin base_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll rather do these steps:

1. commit changes on dev branch
2. push commit to remote dev branch
3. checkout to master branch
4. pull from remote repo
5. merge from dev on master
6. push my master to remote repo